# Click event failing on div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am using the below code:

```
<div class="business-bottom-content" onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='business-bottom-    content-hover';"  onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='business-bottom-content';">
```

The jQuery script is as following:

```
 $("div.business-bottom-content").click(
 function()
  {
   alert('ashutosh mishra');
  });
```

Comment: Some sidenotes: You can use the `:hover` CSS pseudoclass instead of adding a hover class via JavaScript, `javascript:` ***never*** belongs into any `onsomething` attribute, you are setting an invalid class name - get rid of the whitespace before `content-hover`.

Comment: Whats is your question? What doesn't work? the code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/E75tz/1/ (moved JS related code to the Javascript block and not in the HTML markup).

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? Maybe jQuery is not linked properly. Also the html line is bugged but I assume it's a copy-paste issue.

Comment: @voigtan JSFiddle executes the JavaScript when the DOM is ready (use view-source). He is probably calling the JS code before the element exist.

Comment: @RobW could be, can be that he doesn't load jquery at all.

Comment: Really old post I see, but on the mouseover event you're changing the class to "business-bottom-content-hover" but the click event is bound to "business-bottom-content"...and you have to mouseover to "click" it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably define the div after the script has executed.

Wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { .... });` to ensure it executes after the full DOM is available.

Additionally you should get rid of those ugly inline events (if you even need them - you can use `:hover` in CSS):

```
$('div.business-bottom-content').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('business-bottom-content-hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('business-bottom-content-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for div class have to mention "."

```
 $(".business-bottom-content").click(
 function()
 {
      alert('ashutosh mishra');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios even wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() { .... });` may not be enough. In that case, just use a timeout function.

HTML

```
<div id="up-button" class="inc button-number-cart">
 <span class="up-arrow">+</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.button-number-cart',function(){
            event.preventDefault();


            const button = $(this);
            const oldValue = button.parent().parent().find('input').val();
            let newVal;

            if (button.find('.up-arrow').length !== 0) {
                newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
            } else {
                if (oldValue > 0) {
                    newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                } else {
                    newVal = 0;
                }
            }
            button.parent().parent().find('input').val(newVal);
        });
 },700);
```